# 403(Forbidden Error) while sending array of JSON objects to Django using ajax POST method

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I am getting 403(Forbidden Error) while sending array of JSON objects to Django View using ajax POST method. I have already included csrf token but still it is giving the same error. I am making 2 different ajax calls on different events and one of them is working fine while the other one gives 403 error.
Here is my code :

This POST request works fine.

```
$(document).on('submit','#dataset', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'/savedataset/',
          data:{
              lat:$('#lat').val(),
              long:$('#long').val(),
              csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
          },
          success:function (data) {
              alert(data);

          },
          error:function () {
              alert("Error")
          }
      })

  });
```

Here is view.py for the above request :

```
def savedata(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    lat = request.POST['lat']
    long = request.POST['long']

    nsrpt.objects.create(
        latitude=lat,
        longitude=long
    )
response_data = {"lat": lat, "long": long}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

but this one returns the 403 error :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#Save').click(function (e) {
          $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              url:'/savenetwork/',
              dataType:'json',
              data:{
                  networkdata: JSON.stringify(grapharr),
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
              },
              contentType:'application/json',
              success:function (data) {
                  alert(data);
              }

          })

      })

  })
```

Here "grapharr" is a dynamically created array which has json objects at each index and here is view.py for this POST request :

```
import json
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def savenetwork(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = json.load(request.body)
response_data = {"data" : "Test"}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

And here is how the grapharr is created :

```
var grapharr = [];
  function pushtoarray2(lat, long) {
      var lati = lat;
      var longi = long;
      var node = new Object();
      node.latitude = lati;
      node.longitude = longi;
      node.connectednodes = [];
      grapharr.push(node);
  }
```

CSRF token is defined here :

```
<form id="dataset"> {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <p>
      <label>Latitude</label>
      <input id = "lat" value = "" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Longitude</label>
      <input id = "long" value = "" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <button name="Add" value="Add" type="button" onclick="addmarker()">Add</button>
    </p>
    <select id="myselect" multiple size="5">
    </select>
    <p>
      <button name="Connect" value="Connect" type="button" onclick="getSelectValues()">Connect</button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button name="Delete" value="Delete" type="button" onclick="deletelatlong()">Delete</button>
    </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      <p>
      <button id="fetch" name="fetch" value="fetch" type="button">Fetch</button>
    </p>

  </fieldset>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p>
      <button id="Save" name="Save" value="Save" type="button">Save Network</button>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button name="Clear" value="Clear" type="button" onclick="printArray()">Clear Map</button>
    </p>
```

Here is the url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from networkeditor import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
url(r'^savedataset/$', views.savedata),
url(r'^fetchdata/$', views.fetchdata),
url(r'^savenetwork/$', views.savenetwork),
]
```

I tried searching a lot but everywhere it was mentioned to include csrf token which is already there. Please help me out in finding what I am missing here. I am a novice to django/ajax.

Comment: Please show the view and template responsible for rendering the page in the first place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry I didn't get you. I have already posted my code from template as well as view.py

Comment: You haven't posted the template, just a single line of template code. And the view that we want is the one that renders the page with the Ajax on, not the one that receives the Ajax post.

Comment: In jquery ajax, dataType is for server response and not for your request, try add contentType='application/json'.

Comment: what is the result of `JSON.stringify(grapharr)`?

Comment: @JericCruz result is  : [{"latitude":"34.5676","longitude":"-100.6587","connectednodes":[1]},{"latitude":"39.5676","longitude":"-100.6587","connectednodes":[0]}]